# How to return back the imputed values in R

Tags: r, missing-data

Is there any function in R that can help to return imputed values, for example:

```
x <- c(23,23,25,43,34,22,78,NA,98,23,30,NA,21,78,22,76,NA,77,33,98,22,NA,52,87,NA,23,
23)
```

by using single linear imputation method,

```
na.approx(x)
```

I get the imputed data as;

```
[1] 23 23 25 43 34 22 78 35 98 23 30 24 21 78 22 76 22 77 33 98 22 14 52 87 59
[26] 23 23
```

How can I get the imputed value from the program back without looking at the completed dataset one by one?  For example, if the data I imputed contain $n=200$ observations, can I get 20 estimates of the missing value?

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100 percent sure if I got you right, but does this help?

You first save the places, at which the original NA values are, so.e.g the first NA value is at the 8th place. Save this into the dummy variable

```
dummy<-NA
for (i in 1:length(x)){
if(is.na(x[i]))  dummy[i]<-i
}
```

Now get the corresponding values in the imputed data

```
    imputeddata<-na.approx(x)


  for (i in 1:length(imputeddata)){
  if(!is.na(imputeddata[dummy[i]])) print(imputeddata[dummy[i]])
    }
```

Comment: Using the same general principle, you can achieve the same result with *imputeddata[is.na(x)]*

Answer (score 1):

You could use `is.na` to select only those values that were previously `NA`.

```
> x <- c(23,23,25,43,34,22,78,NA,98,23,30,NA,21,78,22,76,NA,77,33,98,22,NA,52,87,NA,23,23)
> na.approx(x)[is.na(x)]
[1] 88.0 25.5 76.5 37.0 55.0
```

Hope that helps.